# Custom object in Oracle stored procedure 11.2.0.4.0

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am calling an Oracle stored procedure in which I have an array of a custom type object. Below is my code.

Type Object:

```
create or replace type xx_wf_svc_ntf_attr_record is object (CITY    varchar(4000),
                                                         COUNTRY  number,
                                                         POP   number,
                                                         CURRENT_DATE date);
```

Table of Object

```
create or replace type XX_WF_SVC_NTF_ATTR_ARRAY is table of XX_WF_SVC_NTF_ATTR_RECORD;
```

Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Respond (
   p_notification_id    IN            NUMBER,
   p_respond_result     IN            VARCHAR2,
   p_respond_comments   IN            VARCHAR2,
   p_responder          IN            VARCHAR2,
   p_attr_array         IN            XX_WF_SVC_NTF_ATTR_ARRAY,
   p_result                OUT NOCOPY NUMBER,
   p_error_code            OUT NOCOPY NUMBER,
   p_error_msg             OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
   FOR i IN p_attr_array.FIRST .. p_attr_array.LAST
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO temp_1 (city,
                          country,
                          pop,
                          CURRENT_DATE)
           VALUES (p_attr_array (i).CITY,
                   p_attr_array (i).COUNTRY,
                   p_attr_array (i).POP,
                   NVL (p_attr_array (i).CURRENT_DATE, SYSDATE));
   END LOOP;

   p_result := 0;
END;
```

Java code :

```
package com.push.db;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Types;

import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;

public class SupplierArray {
    public static void passArray()
    {
        try {
            DBConnectionManager db = new DBConnectionManager();
            Connection conn = db.getConnection();
           CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("call APPS.Respond(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

           STRUCT recStruct = null;
           StructDescriptor recDescriptor = null;
           ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = null;
           ARRAY array = null;
           Object[] objResult = new Object[4];

               recDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("APPS.XX_WF_SVC_NTF_ATTR_RECORD", conn);
               arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor ("APPS.XX_WF_SVC_NTF_ATTR_ARRAY", conn);

               objResult [0] = "kantilal";
               objResult [1] = Integer.parseInt("100");
               objResult [2] = Integer.parseInt("300"); //new Integer(1234);
                objResult [3] = getCurrentDate();
               recStruct = new STRUCT(recDescriptor, conn, objResult);
               STRUCT[] recStructArray = {recStruct};

               array = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, recStructArray);
               cstmt.setInt(1, 1234);
               cstmt.setString(2, "test");      
               cstmt.setString(3, "US");        
               cstmt.setString(4, "I");     
               cstmt.setArray(5, array);    
               cstmt.registerOutParameter(6,Types.NUMERIC);  
               cstmt.registerOutParameter(7,Types.NUMERIC); 
               cstmt.registerOutParameter(8,Types.VARCHAR); 

               cstmt.execute();
               System.out.println("result : " + cstmt.getInt(6));
               System.out.println("msg : " + cstmt.getString(8));
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } 
       }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        passArray();
    }
    public static java.sql.Date getCurrentDate() {
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    return new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
    }

}
```

**In Oracle version : 11.2.0.4.0** 
Only number and date are stored in table named temp_1.  But string value is not stored in the table.  This code works fine in Oracle.

[image: String value is blank]

**In Oracle version : 12.1.0.1.0.**

All data is stored in database.  NO issue.

[image: All data is stored in table]

Test_1 Table :

```
CREATE TABLE temp_1
(
   city           VARCHAR2 (4000),
   country        NUMBER,
   pop            NUMBER,
   CURRENT_DATE   DATE
);
```

I have tried ojdbc5.jar, ojdbc6.jar, ojdbc7.jar etc.  I know this is versioning issue, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Not to your main problem. Replace 'FOR i IN p_attr_array.FIRST .. p_attr_array.LAST LOOP..END LOOP' to 'forall i IN p_attr_array.FIRST .. p_attr_array.LAST' to optimize your plsql code

Comment: This is not working. It gives compile time error....