# Call procedure from Java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I would like to call procedure (Database Oracle) from java with a list of objects in parameter. 
This procedure should insert data in a test table. I tested this procedure and it works. 
But when I call this procedure from Java, objects in the parameter table are empty.

Bellow a simple example that doesn’t work :

Types :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE objectTest AS object (
REFERENCE VARCHAR2(14),
FOURNISSEUR VARCHAR2(14),
CONTRAT VARCHAR2(14)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ListTest as TABLE OF objectTest
```

Procedure (in package):

```
PROCEDURE insertList (p_listTest  IN ListTest ) IS
  v_id pls_integer;
  BEGIN
    v_id := p_listTest.FIRST;
    LOOP
      EXIT WHEN v_id IS NULL;
      INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (REFERENCE, FOURNISSEUR, CONTRAT) VALUES(p_listTest(v_id).REFERENCE, p_listTest(v_id).FOURNISSEUR, p_listTest(v_id).CONTRAT);
  v_id := p_listTest.NEXT(v_id);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Java :

```
final String procedureCall = "{call insertList (?)}";
connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection(); // jdbcTemplate injected
OracleCallableStatement callableSt = (OracleCallableStatement)     connection.prepareCall(procedureCall);
OracleConnection oracleConnection =     connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class)

Struct [] lStruct = new Struct[2];
Object[] lObject1 = new Object[]{"obj1","obj1", "obj1"};
Object[] lObject2 = new Object[]{"obj2","obj2", "obj2"};
lStruct[0] =  oracleConnection.createStruct("OBJECTTEST", lObject1);
lStruct[1] =  oracleConnection.createStruct("OBJECTTEST", lObject2);

Array lArray = oracleConnection.createARRAY("LISTTEST",lStruct);
callableSt.setArray(1,lArray);

//Call Stored Procedure
callableSt.executeUpdate();
```

This code inserts 2 empty rows in my test table. 
I think that the initialization of the objects “Struct” is not correct.

Do you see an error in this example ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works fine. You've shown the code for `insertList` but you're calling `updatePriceList`; either you didn't change the names consistently for posting or you're calling the wrong thing...

Comment: OK, but I compiled and ran your code and it inserted the Java string values into the table columns. (You haven't shown the table definition so I assume it's essentially the same as the object.)

Comment: Yes the table definition is the same as the object. It's works ?! I don't understand why the 2 inserted rows are empty on my project :/ I tested the procedure by creating the table of object in PL/SQL and it was inserted correctly.

Comment: Are you sure they are new rows; only immediate thing I can think is that the way you're getting the connection means it isn't auto-commiting, which is generally a good thing. Do you see any difference if you add an explicit commit from Java?

Comment: It's commited because the 2 empty rows are inserted in my test table. All columns of this table are nullable. So there is no difference when i add an explicit commit :/

Comment: The object data in "lStruct" is null after the execution of "oracleConnection.createStruct". It's maybe the problem but i don't understand why...

Comment: It works with a Number in the type. Here, the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479322/custom-object-in-oracle-stored-procedure-11-2-0-4-0

Do you have an idea to fix it ? I use the Oracle version : 11.2.0.4.0